# How to insert 'require' or 'import' into js file with Webpack 2?

Tags: javascript, import, configuration, webpack, require

### Problem

1. Say I have a structure of modules like this:

```
    ./app-- file.js
         |- some.js
         |- foo.js
         |- and-so-on.js
```

2. In each file I have to write some identical lines like this:

```
    import Foo, { baz, bar } from 'foo';
    import Fee from 'fee';
    import 'zee';
```

3. I feel lazy and don't want to do such a routine by hand.

### Question

How do I do this automatically with the help of Webpack 2, so I don't need to write the same thing again and again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use index.js file into your directory with this content:

```
import Foo from './foo'
import Bar from './bar'
// etc
export Foo
export Bar
// etc
```

And import from each other files:

```
import * from 'your-dir'
```

Comment: I have changed path to Foo maybe it helps, and don't forget to set correctly path to your dir. If it won't work please give me more info about your files structure and recieved errors

Comment: This `import * from 'your-dir'` throws a parsing error, hence, doesn't work.  I didn't get it working. Everybody says that it is impossible to import everything from a module due to possible variables collisions. `export Foo` throws the same error. The next code, however, will work `export { Foo }`. And the question was how to add all this stuff using Webpack. But I had to dig into import/export features and learned something new,  so thank you for your help anyway)

Comment: I accidentally my first comment, so I wrote another one)

Comment: oh yes I forgot:   `import * as libs from 'your-lib-dir'`  thats correct way, but I think it is useless... so maybe the best way is to do not be lazy) Good luck)